# Giving each subset of records a group ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to assign a rank to a subset of records.
Sample data:

```
Colour Code        Size Code
DWMUL040             7
DWMUL040             8
DWMUL040             9
DWMUL040             10
DWMUL040             7
DWMUL040             8
DWMUL040             9
DWMUL040             10
DWMUL040             7
DWMUL040             8
DWMUL040             9
DWMUL040             10
DWMUL040             7
DWMUL040             8
DWMUL040             9
DWMUL040             10
```

I need the data to look like this:

```
Group ID            Colour Code        Size Code
1                   DWMUL040             7
1                   DWMUL040             8
1                   DWMUL040             9
1                   DWMUL040             10
2                   DWMUL040             7
2                   DWMUL040             8
2                   DWMUL040             9
2                   DWMUL040             10
3                   DWMUL040             7
3                   DWMUL040             8
3                   DWMUL040             9
3                   DWMUL040             10
4                   DWMUL040             7
4                   DWMUL040             8
4                   DWMUL040             9
4                   DWMUL040             10
```

The list will be ordered, and basically, whenever the Size Code changes, it is a new group. I have a feeling this one is going to be hard, as the size code (these are garment sizes) could be anything "Such as XL".

Comment: You should be aware that your data is not normalized.

Comment: How can one differentiate between two identical records ? your colour code is the same for all and you have identical sizes as well for the same colours.. is there not unique id for each record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select [colour code], [size code],
         row_number() over (partition by [colour code], [size code]
                            order by 1/0) [group id]
    from tbl
order by [group id], [colour code], [size code];
```